# Create several raster layers based on one layer

Tags: raster, r, terra

The `terra::app()` function accepts one or more layers and a function, and usually (?) returns just a layer with results. However, how to apply a function to one layer that returns more than one layer?

For example, based on the `s` raster, I would like to create a new raster object with four layers, where the values of each layer depend on the previous one:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.6.46
s <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package = "terra"))

my_fun <- function(x, new_nlyr){
  result <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = new_nlyr)
  result[1] <- x
  for (i in seq_len(new_nlyr)[-1]){
    result[i] <- result[i - 1] + 41
  }
  return(result)
}

new_rast <- app(s, my_fun, new_nlyr = 4)
#> Warning in result[1] <- x: number of items to replace is not a multiple of
#> replacement length
#> Error: [app] the number of values returned by 'fun' is not appropriate
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a function that returns a matrix where the number of rows is the number of layers you want in the output, and the number of columns is the same as the length of the input value:

```
> mf = function(x){return(rbind(rep(1,length(x)), rep(99,length(x))))}
> mf(1:5)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]   99   99   99   99   99
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-18 by cutting and pasting.</sup>

Then you get a raster with multiple layers out, where here `s` is the sample raster you are using:

```
> n = app(s, mf)
> dim(n)
[1] 90 95  2
> n
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 90, 95, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : memory 
names       : lyr.1, lyr.2 
min values  :     1,    99 
max values  :     1,    99
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-18 by cutting and pasting.</sup>

So I think in your use case you need to use basic matrix ops like rbind etc to put together the outputs you need given the inputs.